# good non-interactive slideshow plugin for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I need a slideshow-plugin, with visual appearance similar to startpage of http://modx.com/,
no interaction (page selectors) however, just timed slides. bg-images + text.

Any recommendations?

thanks

//t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy Nivo Slider for sure.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-nivo-slider/

Answer (score 1):

I've had good results with Content Slide. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-slide/

Comment: thanks, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-slide/ says up to 3.0.5 however. I'll go for nivo.